# Rotation of a freely falling body

Tags: rotational-dynamics, free-fall

Suppose a straight rod with one end denser than the other is dropped from a height at an angle. Will the rod hit the ground at the same angle or will air resistance cause it to straighten and hit the ground with the denser end? What will happen if the same thing is repeated in vacuum?

Comment: Do you mean heavier or denser ? If the former, specify the exact shape of the rod.

Comment: I meant denser as the rod is straight. Fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The denser end has less bouyancy and will start tilting downwards eventually in a precessing motion. when damped it will point straight down.

In a vacuum, the entire rod will have no bouyancy, so it will drop straight down without experiencing any torque.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment got me thinking, what if the rod had even density, but was shaped like an elongated pear?

Comment: bouyancy would be the same everywhere but the weight-to-drag ratio would be bigger on the fat end, so the fat end would drop faster. (large rain drops fall faster than small ones and hail even faster despite equal density)